# Can't Get the Desired Text in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sorry if the below formatting is incorrect.  I'm trying to scrape just the "Jane Doe" section of the below html

```
<div class="col1 client">
   <a name="12345"></a>
   "Jane Doe"
   <div class="request"><i>insurance claim</i></div>        
</div>
```

My code at the bottom will output both "Jane Doe" and *insurance claim*.  How can I just get the "Jane Doe" text?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
listings = soup.find(id="listings")
listing_items = listings.find_all(class_="col1 client")
```

Comment: Was this answered?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use next_sibling

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="col1 client">
   <a name="12345"></a>
   "Jane Doe"
   <div class="request"><i>insurance claim</i></div>        
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".col1.client a"):
    print(item.next_sibling)
```

Or

```
print([item.next_sibling.strip() for item in soup.select(".col1.client a")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another usage might be the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldocs = """
<div class="col1 client">
   <a name="12345"></a>
   "Jane Doe"
   <div class="request"><i>insurance claim</i></div>        
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldocs, 'html5lib')
for item in soup.select(".request"):
    print(item.previous_sibling.strip())
```